# Is my light fixture shorted? Circuit detective is reading multiple breakers

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

I live in a fairly old house, as an upstairs tenant. We we bought a window AC unit and about the same time as summer started the kitchen light which appears to be on a different breaker started flicker and eventually died (no indication of power anywhere in the fixture).
I bought a Harbor Freight circuit detective, and it seems to read multiple breakers on the panel.
The logical reasoning would be that I’m just misreading the circuit detector, but some of these breakers are directly next to each other on the panel.
Could it be due to the light dying at the same time as the regular use of the AC, and the multiple detections, that there’s a short somewhere and the AC fried the light?

Comment: As a tenant you need to get the landlord to bring in a licensed electrician.  You and the landlord are basically only allowed to change light bulbs and plug stuff in(some other very minor stuff).  An old house might have electrical problems, low power available, bad wiring.

Comment: In addition to what crip659 said, your question, as written, is unclear and hard to follow.

Comment: Even a high end version of the ‘circuit detective’ gives hints, not truth. And @crip659 — that’s an answer.

Comment: Your belief that the new AC caused some phantom circuit to fry a light fixture or the wiring to it is not plausible.   There is a realistic reason for the issues.  With a home that is old , you really need to get with the landlord and a professional should be called in.  The circuit detector is very finicky  and misreading is easily done if not used carefully.

Comment: Could well be an old (no handle tie) Multi-Wire-Branch-Circuit. Or a less old one improperly done. Regardless, it's not DIY in that living situation.

Comment: "Circuit trackers" are almost useless on old, ungrounded wiring systems, with possible multiple interconnections, intentional or not, between different circuits. And the problem with the light is almost certainly some sort of "open", which is the opposite of a "short".